# Envers query returns a lazy result instead of an eager one

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have an Envers query that returns a lazy result although the field is defined in hibernate-mapping with lazy="false".

I have looked it up at the Hibernate-Envers forums and didn't find any useful information.

So this is what i have:

hibernate-mapping -
[image: hibernate-mapping]

This is the result during run-time

[image: This is the result during run-time]

Any idea about what am I doing wrong or how can i get the real object instead of the lazy one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eager loading is not supported by Envers. All relationships are lazy.

[Source](http://community.jboss.org/message/628530?tstart=0)

Comment: So what should I do, if want to get the real object or to get a more detailed Proxy? it's not a HibernateProxy object so i can't really use  - (HibernateProxy)proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();

Comment: One thing you could do is just not use the Envers API and use plain JPA. You then would have to model your audit tables as @Entity(s). We had to do this due to the major limitations of the Envers API, and I think this way you might be able to overcome the lazy initialization issues too.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any plan of adding eager loading support to Envers?

Comment: I've already request this and the answer was no :( PS: we're not having so much of an issue now that we're using the OSIV Filter over the Interceptor...if that helps at all